# Java: Method chaining in derived class

Tags: java

I am writing a DerivedClass (extends SuperClass) with method chaining. For example,

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int responseCode;
    protected String responseMessage;

    public void setResponseCode(int code) {
            this.responseCode = code;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
            return responseCode;
    }

    public SuperClass withResponseCode(int code) {
            setResponseCode(code);
            return this;
    }

    public void setResponseMessage(String message) {
            this.responseMessage = message;
    }

    public String getResponseMessage() {
            return responseMessage;
    }

    public SuperClass withResponseMessage(String message) {
            setResponseMessage(message);
            return this;
    }
```

}

And

```
public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass {
    protected String credentialType;
    protected String credentialId;

    public void setCredentialType(String type) {
            this.credentialType = type;
    }

    public String getCredentialType() {
            return credentialType;
    }

    public DerivedClass withCredentialType(String type) {
            setCredentialType(type);
            return this;
    }


    public void setCredentialId(String id) {
            this.credentialId = id;
    }

    public String getCredentialId() {
            return credentialId;
    }

    public DerivedClass withCredentialId(String id) {
            setCredentialId(id);
            return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            /*dc.setResponseCode(200);
            dc.setResponseMessage("SUCCESS");
            dc.setCredentialType("MobileIdentifier");
            dc.setCredentialId("678882");*/

            dc.withResponseCode(200)
                    .withResponseMessage("SUCCESS")
                    .withCredentialType("MobileIdentifier")
                    .withCredentialId("678882");

            System.out.println("Derived Class: Code - " + dc.getResponseCode() + " - Response Message - " + dc.getResponseMessage() + " - Credential Type - " + dc.getCredentialType());
    }
```

}

During compilation of the above I am getting:

```
DerivedClass.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                    .withCredentialType("MobileIdentifier")
                    ^
symbol:   method withCredentialType(String)
location: class SuperClass
1 error
```

Why am I getting this when CredentialType is a field in DerivedClass and not in the SuperClass? How can I chain mixed methods from SuperClass & DerivedClass using the DerivedClass object?

Comment: Because your call to `withResponseMessage` returns a `SuperClass` and `SuperClass` doesn't have the method `withCredentialType`.

Comment: it has it - public SuperClass withResponseMessage(String message)

Comment: That's not the one I am talking about. That method returns a `SuperClass` and then you try to call the method `withCredentialType` on that returned object which doesn't work because that method **does not exist** in `SuperClass`.

Comment: If you really want to chain it then overridde withResponseMessage in your DerivedClass or else like @takendarkk suggested, downcast it and then call with .withCredentialType

Comment: The difficulty here, perhaps, exemplifies the general rule that "the Builder pattern can not easily be implemented for classes that can be extended by its clients".

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you are getting that compilation error because the methods of your `SuperClass` return the `SuperClass` type, which doesn't contain your `DerivedClass`'s methods.

The correct way to solve this is to make `SuperClass` abstract and use generics on `SuperClass` with a recursive type (also called an [F-bound type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)):

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>> {

    // TODO attributes, getters and setters

    public T withResponseCode(int code) {
        setResponseCode(code);
        return (T) this; // this cast is absolutely safe!
    }

    // TODO other SuperClass builder methods
}
```

Then, you can define your `DerivedClass` as follows:

```
public class DerivedClass extends SuperClass<DerivedClass> {

    // TODO attributes, getters and setters

    public DerivedClass withCredentialType(String type) {
        setCredentialType(type);
        return this;
    }

    // TODO other DerivedClass builder methods
}
```

And there won't be any more compilation errors. The downside of this approach is that it forces you to make the `SuperClass` class abstract, in order to only use the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

The method `withReponseMessage()` returns an object of type `SuperClass`.

The class `SuperClass` has no method called `withCredentialType()` which is why you get the error message.

One strategy for solving this problem is to make `SuperClass` abstract, and then to define all API methods there, even if the methods are abstract.  Otherwise, you will have to cast the object that is returned from the 1st method call (which might make your program vulnerable to mismatch exceptions in the future.

Comment: This works.

dc.withCredentialType("MobileIdentifier")
                        .withCredentialId("678882")
                        .withResponseCode(200)
                        .withResponseMessage("SUCCESS");

Comment: The order in this case makes a difference

Comment: If the order makes a difference then you have not followed the design pattern properly.

Comment: While you can document carefully in your doc comments for your derived class that subclass methods much always be invoked first, you'll still have a situation in which invoking a superclass method followed by a subclass method will result in errors.  This may be confusing to other programmers or users of your API ... but if this is a strictly in-house class that will never be released in any way, I can't say that it's wrong.  I mean, if it works, it works (even if it's ugly).  The solution will always be brittle.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to downcast it to `DerivedClass`, or, use a `DerivedClass` instance from the beginning.